# Page miss in Cache Replacement

Tags: algorithm, caching, page-replacement

I am studying about 2Q Cache Replacement Policy and i came across [this post](https://medium.com/@koushikmohan/an-analysis-of-2q-cache-replacement-algorithms-21acceae672a).

They have worked out an example with the following page keys [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and cache memory of 5 pages. A1in size is 2 and A1out size is 3.

[image] 
 
For the 10th page (i.e) 3, even though the page is available in A1out, why is it a **cache miss**?

They fixed a cache size of `5`, so searching for 5 elements from Am and A1in has been completed.

Even then we found that page in a buffer. So Why isn't it a hit.

Comment: A1out is a non-resident queue for evicted items that are being monitored. That means that while the key was found, it's value is absent and had to be fetched. A hit in A1out is still a cache miss, but it now promotes the item to Am as a more valuable entry for the cache to keep long-term.